# Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8 was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1+gzip'

Tags: .net, wcf, compression, gzip, wcf-binding

I'm trying to implement Gzip compression in a WCF Service that is hosted on IIS.

Previously the binding config was set as --

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="SOAPBinding">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Now to implement compression, I'm changing the binding config to --

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="SOAPBinding">
        <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Once I make the changes, whenever I'm trying to get the response for the endpoint (testing using SOAP UI), it returning error response as

`Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8 was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1+gzip'.`

With the previous binding config, the service is working fine. Once I'm changing the custom Binding it is throwing the error.

Expectation is when the Accept-Encoding : gzip, is sent in the request the service should return the response with header Content-Encoding : gzip, once the compression is enabled

Comment: First of all, I suggest you change the version of soap to Soap 1.1. Then I think this post can help you solve the problem.[How do you send a ZIP file in the request body in SoapUI / ReadyAPI](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22224/how-do-you-send-a-zip-file-in-the-request-body-in-soapui-readyapi)

Comment: How to set the soap version to 1.1 within custom binding ?

Comment: Under **Web.Config** **<binding> ** there is one ** <textMessageEncoding>**that can be used to specify the Soap version. You can see this document for details[<textMessageEncoding>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/textmessageencoding)